# Using __thread in c++0x

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I read that there was a new keyword in C++: it's `__thread` from what I've read.

All I know is that it's a keyword to be used like the `static` keyword but I know nothing else. Does this keyword just mean that, for instance, if a variable were declared like so:

```
__thread int foo;
```

then anything to do with that variable will be executed with a new thread?

Comment: Where did you read that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's `thread_local`, not `__thread`. It's used to define  variables which has storage duration of the thread.

`thread_local` is a *new* storage duration specifier added in C++0x. There are other storage duration :  *static*, *automatic* and *dynamic*.

From [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration):

> **thread local** storage duration (C++11 feature). The variable is allocated when the thread begins and deallocated when the thread ends. Each thread has its own instance of the variable. Only variables declared thread_local have this storage duration.

---

I think the introduction of this keyword was made possible by introducing a standardized memory model in C++0x:

- [C++11 introduced a standardized memory model. What does it mean? And how is it going to affect C++ programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319146/c0x-introduces-a-standardized-memory-model-what-does-it-mean-and-how-is-it-go)

Comment: whoa, the answer looks completely different than it did 3 minutes ago.

Comment: "`thread_local` is a new storage duration specifier added in C++03": What nonsense is this?!

Comment: @Tomalak: You know that it was not a "nonsense" but a "typo", don't you?

Comment: Unfortunately Apple still doesn't want you using it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094794/why-does-apple-clang-disallow-c11-thread-local-when-official-clang-supports

Comment: __thread is supported on GNU, clang and more. It was available before thread_local... they are not equivalent and both are supported. the difference is that thread_local uses lazy initialization to initialize the variable in only threads that access it. __thread does not initialize at all and you must manually initialize it per thread. thread_local thus has an overhead per access and __thread does not. Apple's compilers disable thread_local and not thread because of this inefficiency, Although __thread is not available on all compilers, __thread is available with GNU tools.

Comment: I've seen `__thread` used on functions. What's the meaning of it there?

Answer (score 22):

From [the Wikipedia article on "Thread-local storage"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage#C.2B.2B):

> Thread-local storage (TLS) is a computer programming method that uses
>   static or global memory local to a thread.
>
> This is sometimes needed because normally all threads in a process
>   share the same address space, which is sometimes undesirable.

And:

> C++0x introduces the `thread_local` keyword. Aside that, various C++
>   compiler implementations provide specific ways to declare thread-local
>   variables:
>
> Sun Studio C/C++, IBM XL C/C++, GNU C and Intel C/C++ (Linux systems) use the syntax:
>
> ```
>     __thread int number;
> ```
>
> Visual C++, Intel C/C++ (Windows systems), Borland C++ Builder and Digital Mars C++ use the syntax:
>
> ```
>     __declspec(thread) int number;
> ```
>
> Borland C++ Builder also supports the syntax:
>
> ```
>     int __thread number;
> ```

So, whilst `__thread` *does* exist in practice and on some systems, `thread_local` is the new, official, C++0x keyword that does the same thing.

Prefer it to non-standard `__thread` whenever you have access to C++0x.

Answer (score 5):

The keyword is called `thread_local`. It means that each thread has its own version of that variable.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does *not* mean that "anything to do with that variable will be executed with a new thread". It means that there will be a copy of the variable for each thread that exists, and each thread can only see its own copy of the variable.