# Is __thread guaranteed to be zero initalized?

Tags: c++, thread-local-storage

I have two variables. One is `__thread` the other is `static __thread`. If I had a constructor all I'd do is zero all the member variables. I also happen to use this class only outside of function bodies. Will my variables be zero initalized skipping the need for me to write a constructor?

---

To clarify. I have a class that is defined as `__thread Foo foo` and `static __thread Foo foo`. I don't mean I have a variable literally named __thread that I somehow tricked the compiler to let me use without naming a type. I'm positive static is zero initialized but IDK if __thread undoes it or if __thread without static will be zero initalized

Comment: `__thread` is not a thing in C++. This is a C keyword which has no meaning in C++.

Comment: @NicolBolas Some compilers support that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7047301/2527795

Comment: @NicolBolas It's a gcc extension that clang supports

Comment: If you're using C++, why don't you use the actual C++ language feature for creating thread-local variables?

Comment: @NicolBolas TBH I should have tagged this differently. It is C++ at the moment but I may downgrade to C. I hear thread_local does more work and supports non trivial constructors which I don't need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread-local variables are zero initialized before any other constructors. If you have no constructors, then only the zero initialization is done. In case of a class type, this means all members are set to zero.

> Zero initialization is performed in the following situations:
>
> 1. For every named variable with static or thread-local storage duration that is not subject to constant initialization, before any other initialization.

> If T is an non-union class type, all base classes and non-static data members are zero-initialized, and all padding is initialized to zero bits. The constructors, if any, are ignored.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization