# Does seq_cst ordering guarantee immediate visibility?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

N3243 1.10.21 says

> It can be shown that programs that correctly use mutexes and memory_order_
>   seq_cst operations to prevent all data races and use no other synchronization operations behave as if the
>   operations executed by their constituent threads were simply interleaved, with each value computation of an
>   object being taken from the last side effect on that object in that interleaving. This is normally referred to as “sequential consistency”.

Does this mean that any **seq_cst** writes on an atomic object are immediately visible to other threads which read the atomic object with **seq_cst** ordering ?

Comment: Be careful. In MT programming, what comes first, later, or immediately is **not** clearly defined. Of course, delayed indefinitely is a clear concept, and so is delayed for ridiculously long. Compilers should make sure neither happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is nothing in the C++ standard that guarantees immediate visibility.

Atomic writes should become visible to other threads within a "reasonable" period of time, but they do not have to be immediate, and there is no precise definition of "reasonable".

What **is** guaranteed is that there is a single total order of `memory_order_seq_cst` operations. A read that does not see the value written must therefore occur earlier in that total order than the write. Since this total order encompasses **all** variables and **all** `memory_order_seq_cst` operations, if there is any communication between the threads at all, then writes must become visible pretty quickly.

Comment: "_A read that does not see the value written must therefore occur earlier in that total order than the write_" How is that different for other orders?

Comment: If your loads use `memory_order_acquire` then if two threads both read both of two different variables `x` and `y`, then they can disagree on the order of a change to `x` relative to a change to `y`. With `memory_order_seq_cst` they must agree.

Comment: Another way to state part of what `seq_cst` guarantees: this store will be visible to other threads *before any other seq_cst operations from this thread*.  Which might be achieved in practice with a full memory barrier after a seq_cst store, or by having later seq_cst operations wait, if there are any before this store has a chance to commit to coherent cache (and thus become globally visible.)

Comment: So stronger ordering makes this thread wait before doing other stuff, not pushing stores out any faster.  See [Does hardware memory barrier make visibility of atomic operations faster in addition to providing necessary guarantees?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61591287) for more about that common misconception.