# Which one performs better: load(memory_order_seq_cst) or atomic_fetch_add(0, memory_order_relaxed) on X86?

Tags: c++, x86, x86-64, atomic, stdatomic

**Question 1**: I have a variable primarily used for counting, only concerned with its own value. Which of the following two approaches has better performance?

Approach 1:

```
Read:  aaa.fetch_add(0, memory_order_relaxed)
Write: aaa.fetch_add(1, memory_order_relaxed)
```

Approach 2:

```
Read:  aaa.load(memory_order_seq_cst)
Write: aaa.fetch_add(1, memory_order_seq_cst)
```

**Question 2**: If thread T1: `aaa` may have already existed in T1's storebuffer, will T1's atomic RMW operation flush the storebuffer?

Comment: 1. [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Assuming you are on 680x0 architecture, the first one is faster.  But if you are on a different architecture, maybe the second one is faster.  Do you care about cross-architecture performance, or a specific architecture?

Comment: I wouldn't trust (1) to be equivalent to (2).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: They certainly aren't equivalent for every possible surrounding code (e.g. no syncs-with in the abstract machine), but they might both be strong enough for some use-cases.  I'm a bit curious exactly what invariant they need to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Expect the pure load to be *much* faster.**  Atomic RMWs are slow, pure loads are fast.  Atomic RMWs will dirty the cache line.  (Or clang optimizes `aaa.fetch_add(0, relaxed)` into `mfence` + `mov`-load: https://godbolt.org/z/adEP7Tcx1)

On x86, a `seq_cst` load requires no extra barriers, so is as cheap as a `relaxed` load, other than compile-time reordering. Pure loads are vastly faster than any RMW, like 3 per clock vs. 1 per 20 clocks in the no-contention case, and pure loads scale with multiple parallel readers.  (https://uops.info/ look at `lock xadd` vs. `mov r32, mem`)

Atomic RMWs are full barriers on x86; in asm there's no way to make them weaker than `seq_cst`.  (So yes, they have to wait for the store-buffer to drain.)  Only `.store(val, seq_cst)` requires any extra barrier instruction (typically a `lock add byte [rsp], 0` because that's faster than `mfence` on many CPUs.)

On some non-x86 like PowerPC or maybe ARMv7, perhaps a `relaxed` RMW could be cheaper than a `seq_cst` load in some contexts.  But unlikely on ARMv8 (including 32-bit mode) where `seq_cst` is only as strong as necessary, with a special interaction between SC stores and SC loads, allowing StoreLoad reordering otherwise.

In terms of inter-thread latency, both should perform the same; the [store buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141366/can-a-speculatively-executed-cpu-branch-contain-opcodes-that-access-ram) already tries to drain itself as fast as possible to avoid becoming full and stalling.  (The front-end has to allocate a store-buffer entry when issuing a store uop from the front-end into the back-end, so not doing this would be worse for how far ahead out-of-order exec can see.) See *[Does hardware memory barrier make visibility of atomic operations faster in addition to providing necessary guarantees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591287/does-hardware-memory-barrier-make-visibility-of-atomic-operations-faster-in-addi)* (no)