# Is it safe to change the reactor's state using the async API without manual synchronization?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, grpc, grpc-c++

### Hey

I'm using gRPC with the async API. That requires constructing reactors based on classes like [ClientBidiReactor](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/client_callback.h#L240) or [ServerBidiReactor](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/70fa55155beade94670661f033e91b55f43c9dee/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/server_callback.h#L270)

If I understand correctly, the gRPC works like this: It takes threads from some thread pool, and using these threads it executes certain methods of the reactors that are being used.

### The problem

Now, the problem is when the reactors become stateful. I know that the methods of a single reactor will most probably be executed sequentially, but they may be run from different threads, is this correct? If so, then is it possible that we may encounter a problem described for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798873/visibility-in-concurrent-c-programs)?

Long story short, if we have an unsynchronized state in such circumstances, is it possible that one thread will update the state, then a next method from the reactor will be executed from a different thread and it will see the not-updated value because the state's new value has not been flushed to the main memory yet?

Honestly, I'm a little confused about this. In the grpc examples [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/5a2422f42ac7f68be486bd8d9bd68458761419b6/examples/cpp/route_guide/route_guide_callback_server.cc#L195) and [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/route_guide/route_guide_callback_client.cc#L232) this doesn't seem to be addressed (the mutex is for a different purpose there and the values are not atomic).

I used/linked examples for the bidi reactors but this refers to all types of reactors.

### Conclusion / questions

There are basically a couple of questions from me at this point:

- Are the concerns valid here and do I properly understand everything or did I miss something? Does the problem exist?
- Do we need to manually synchronize reactors' state or is it handled by the library somehow(I mean is flushing to the main memory handled)?
- Are the library authors aware of this? Did they keep this in mind while they were coding examples I linked?

Thank you in advance for any help, all the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the examples don't showcase this very well, there's some room for improvement. The operation-completion reaction methods (`OnReadInitialMetadataDone`, `OnReadDone`, `OnWriteDone`, ...) can be called concurrently from different threads owned by the gRPC library, so if your code accesses any shared state, you'll want to coordinate that yourself (via synchronization, lock-free types, etc). In practice, I'm not sure how often it happens, or which callbacks are more likely to overlap.

The original callback API spec says a bit more about this, under a "Thread safety" clause: [L67: C++ callback-based asynchronous API](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L67-cpp-callback-api.md#:%7E:text=Thread%20safety%3A%20the%20above%20calls%20may%20take%20place%20concurrently%2C%20except%20that%20OnDone%20will%20always%20take%20place%20after%20all%20other%20reactions.%20No%20further%20RPC%20operations%20are%20permitted%20to%20be%20issued%20after%20OnDone%20is%20invoked.). The same is reiterated a few places in the callback implementation code itself - [client_callback.h#L234-236](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/f11d86c403e45ac4d13662f71d79512cd7e26bde/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/client_callback.h#L234-L236) for example.