# C++ language memory model

Tags: java, c++, memory, model, specifications

I do not understand how Java could rely on C++ code at the times of C++ hadn't a memory model ? I mean, Java had memory model all the time ! But it's written using C++ language which hadn't one until C++11 version of the language.

How could it be possible ? Please, bring some light !

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `memory model`?

Comment: @PomfCaster the rules of the language that determine execution order, visibility etc. in a multi threaded execution of a program.

Comment: Java's memory model was considered broken by many until Java 5.

Comment: @PomfCaster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319146/

Comment: Can you please explain what specific problem would exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible because Java VMs were written using non-portable knowledge of the memory models of the implementations of C++ that compiled them.

The introduction of a memory model into C++11 is useful since it provides a standard model, and so future C++ code does not need to rely on detailed knowledge of particular C++ implementations.