# Atomic pointers in c++ and passing objects between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, memory-model

My question involves `std::atomic<T*>` and the data that this pointer points to.  If in thread 1 I have

```
Object A;
std:atomic<Object*> ptr;
int bar = 2;
A.foo = 4;  //foo is an int;
ptr.store(*A);
```

and if in thread 2 I observe that `ptr` points to `A`, can I be guaranteed that `ptr->foo` is 4 and `bar` is 2?

Does the default memory model for the atomic pointer (sequentially consistent) guarantee that assignments on non-atomic (in this case `A.foo`) that happen before an atomic store will be seen by other threads before it sees the assignment of the same `atomic.store` for both cases?

If it helps or matters, I am using x64 (and I only care about this platform), gcc (with a version that supports atomics).

Comment: I think you mean `ptr.store(&A)`? `ptr.store(*A)` makes no sense (unless `Object` defines `Object * Object::operator*();`...).

Comment: Related: [C++11 introduced a standardized memory model. What does it mean? And how is it going to affect C++ programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319146/c11-introduced-a-standardized-memory-model-what-does-it-mean-and-how-is-it-g)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer is yes and perhaps no

**The memory model principles:**

C++11 atomics use [by default](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/store/) the `std::memory_order_seq_cst` memory ordering, which means that operations are **sequentially consistent**.

The semantics of this is that ordering of all operations are as if all these operations were performed sequentially :

- C++ standard section 29.3/3 explains how this works for **atomics**:  "*There shall be a single total order S on all memory_order_seq_cst operations, consistent with the **“happens before”** order and modification orders for all affected locations, such that each memory_order_seq_cst
  operation that loads a value observes either the last preceding modification according to this order S, or the result of an operation that is not memory_order_seq_cst.*"
- The section 1.10/5 explains how this impacts **also non-atomics**: "*The library defines a number of atomic operations (...) that are specially identified as synchronization operations. These operations play a special role in making assignments in one thread visible to another.*"

The answer to your question is yes !

**Risk with non-atomic data**

You shall however be aware that in reality the consistency guarantee is more limited for the non-atomic values.

Suppose a first execution scenario:

```
(thread 1) A.foo = 10; 
(thread 1) A.foo = 4;     //stores an int
(thread 1) ptr.store(&A); //ptr is set AND synchronisation 
(thread 2) int i = *ptr;  //ptr value is safely accessed (still &A) AND synchronisation
```

Here, `i` is 4.  Because `ptr` is atomic, thread (2) safely gets the value `&A` when it reads the pointer.  The memory ordering ensures that all assignments made BEFORE `ptr`  are seen by the other threads ("happens before" constraint).

But suppose a second execution scenario:

```
(thread 1) A.foo = 4;     //stores an int
(thread 1) ptr.store(&A); //ptr is set AND synchronisation 
(thread 1) A.foo = 8;     // stores int but NO SYNCHRONISATION !! 
(thread 2) int i = *ptr;  //ptr value is safely accessed (still &A) AND synchronisation
```

Here the result is undefined. It could be 4 because of the memory ordering guaranteed that what happens before the `ptr` assignement is seen by the other threads.  But nothing prevents assignments made afterwards to be seen as well. So it could be 8.

If you would have had `*ptr = 8;` instead of `A.foo=8;` then you would have certainty again: `i` would be 8.

You can verify this experimentally with this for example:

```
void f1() {  // to be launched in a thread
    secret = 50; 
    ptr = &secret; 
    secret = 777; 
    this_thread::yield();
}
void f2() { // to be launched in a second thread
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
    int i = *ptr; 
    cout << "Value is " << i << endl;
}
```

**Conclusions**

To conclude, the answer to your question is yes, but only if no other change to the non atomic data happens after the synchronisation.  The main risk is that only `ptr` is atomic.  But this does not apply to the values pointed to.

To be noted that especially pointers bring further synchronisation risk when you reassign the atomic pointer to a non atomic pointer.

Example:

```
// Thread (1): 
std::atomic<Object*> ptr;
A.foo = 4;  //foo is an int;
ptr.store(*A);

// Thread (2): 
Object *x; 
x=ptr;      // ptr is atomic but x not !  
terrible_function(ptr);   // ptr is atomic, but the pointer argument for the function is not !
```

Comment: I think, there is an ':' missing in line 1

Comment: `Object *x = ptr;` is safe, it's doing an atomic load the same as `ptr.load()` to get a plain `Object*` (the `T` in `std::atomic<T>`).  Deref of the resulting `x` pointer is exactly the same as your `*ptr`, which is equivalent to `*(ptr.load())`.  (std::atomic defines  conversion operator to its value type as equivalent to `.load()`.)  I think you're calling it unsafe because you're thinking it works like `reinterpret_cast<Object**>( &atomic_ptr )` or something, which would do a non-atomic access to the shared memory if you dereferenced it.  But that's not the case.

Comment: In your "second scenario" where the writer thread does another store to the payload after updating the pointer, it's not just the result that's undefined.  The *behaviour* is undefined, of the whole program, because that's data-race UB.  In practice on real CPUs, yes it's extremely likely that you'll just get either `4` or `8`, but unsynchronized write+read is UB in C++.

Comment: BTW, in your last code block, `ptr.store(*A);` is supposed to be `ptr.store(&A);` - the code in the question got that wrong but you didn't comment on it.

Comment: Also, the other way for this to break is if the reader did `ptr.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)`.  Which in theory doesn't guarantee ordering since that's even weaker than `memory_order_consume`, but in practice the data dependency will create ordering except on DEC Alpha.  Or if the compiler was able to prove that the only possible value `Object *x` could have was `&A`, and optimized away the data dependency.  e.g. if you did `if(x == &A){ return x->foo; }` it could optimize to `A.foo`.

Comment: @PeterCordes can you please provide the reference to the C++ standard that guarantees that `Object *x = ptr;` is atomic ?

Comment: `std::atomic::operator T()` is "equivalent to `load()`".   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T .  Dereferencing the plain pointer you get from the load is not atomic, just like it's not when you do it as part of the same expression like `*ptr` or `*ptr.load()`.  The atomic object holds a pointer, accesses to that pointer value are atomic.  Deref of the resulting pointer to get to the final `Object` are not atomic.

Comment: That's why it's data-race UB for the writer to do `A.foo = 8` after publishing a pointer to that non-atomic object, not just an uncertain result like if you had `std::atomic<Object> A`.

Answer (score 7):

By default, C++-11 atomic operations have acquire/release semantics.

So a thread that see's your store will also see all operations performed before it.

You can find some more details [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order).

Comment: +1. (Actually the default is `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, which has even stronger guarantees than acquire/release, but indeed that's all that would be required here anyway.)