# Is it always necessary for a notifying thread to lock the shared data during modification?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, condition-variable

When using a condition variable, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable describes the typical steps for the thread that notifies as:

> 1. acquire a std::mutex (typically via std::lock_guard)
> 2. perform the modification while the lock is held
> 3. execute notify_one or notify_all on the std::condition_variable (the lock does not need to be held for notification)

For the simple case shown below, is it necessary for the main thread to lock "stop" when it modifies it? While I understand that locking when modifying shared data is almost always a good idea, I'm not sure why it would be necessary in this case.

```
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mutex;
bool stop = false;

void worker() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    cv.wait(lock, [] { return stop; })
}

// No lock (Why would this not work?)
void main() {
     std::thread(worker);
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
     stop = true;
     cv.notify_one();
}

// With lock: why is this neccesary?
void main() {
     std::thread mythread(worker);
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
     {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex);
         stop = true;
     }
     cv.notify_one();
     mythread.join();
}
```

Comment: Your code `terminate`s because you're destroying a unjoined thread. Please run some basic tests on your code before posting.

Comment: Sorry about that- added a join.

Comment: I assume you are aware of following sentence in the docs and you are asking _why_ this may be? _"Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified under the mutex in order to correctly publish the modification to the waiting thread."_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For the simple case shown below, is it necessary for the main thread to lock "stop" when it modifies it?

Yes, to prevent race condition. Aside from issues of accessing shared data from different threads, which could be fixed by `std::atomic`, imagine this order of events:

```
worker_thread: checks value of `stop` it is false
main_thread: sets `stop` to true and sends signal
worker_thread: sleeps on condition variable
```

In this situation worker thread would possibly sleep forever and it would miss event of `stop` set to `true` simply because wakeup signal was already sent and it missed it.

Acquiring mutex on modification of shared data is required because only then you can treat checking condition and going to sleep or acting on it in worker thread as atomic operation as whole.

Answer (score 1):

Is , it is necessary. 
First of all, from the standard point of view, you code exhibits undefined behavior,  as `stop` is not atomic and isn't change under a lock, while other threads may read or write to it. 
 both reading and writing must occur under a lock if multiple threads read and write to a shared memory.

From hardware perspective, if `stop` isn't changed under a lock, other threads, even through they lock some lock, aren't guaranteed to "see" the change that was done. locks don't just prevent from other threads to intervene, they also force the latest change to be read or written into the main memory, and hence all the threads can work with the latest values.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Do you have a link for any additional resources on this subject?

Comment: @mmnormyle, I don't know the answer for C++ specifically, but in some languages, what you're after is called the language's _memory model_.  For example, there is a sectinon called ["Memory Model"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) in the Java language specification, and basically it talks about under what conditions one thread will see the changes made in memory by some other thread.  Note that C++ did not have a formal memory model until one of the more recent versions.  Prior to that, all multi-threading was implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I found a decent SO answer on the topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319146/c11-introduced-a-standardized-memory-model-what-does-it-mean-and-how-is-it-g