# std::memory_order_relaxed and initialization

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, atomic, memory-barriers

Is the following guaranteed to print 1 followed by 2?

```
auto&& atomic = std::atomic<int>{0};
std::atomic<int>* pointer = nullptr;

// thread 1
auto&& value = std::atomic<int>{1};
pointer = &value;
atomic.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
while (atomic.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != 2) {}
cout << value.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) << endl;

// thread 2
while (atomic.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != 1) {}
cout << pointer->load(std::memory_order_relaxed); << endl;
pointer->fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
atomic.store(2, std::memory_order_relaxed) {}
```

If not, what are the possible outputs here?  What does the standard say about initialization and memory orders for this case?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is undefined behavior

Comment: @curiousguy12 Could you explain?  It seems like the atomic variable should be properly initialized before its address can be taken?

Comment: Sorry, did not include explanation.. `pointer` in th1 is assigned an address followed by `atomic.store(1, relaxed)`. Th2 picks up that store, but based on relaxed ordering, there is no synchronization; i.e., th2 may dereference `pointer` while it is still `nullptr`

Comment: In your comment, the core issue is in the word "before". Without synchronization, there is no before or after. Access to `pointer` is simply unordered

Comment: That makes sense to me, do you want to turn that into an answer?

Comment: @Curious You have a **data race**, that's UB for you. No amount of `std::atomic` use will cancel that.

Comment: One of the best explanations [C++11 introduced a standardized memory model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319146/c11-introduced-a-standardized-memory-model-what-does-it-mean-and-how-is-it-g)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the use of 'relaxed' ordering prevents any necessary inter-thread synchronization from happening and so, access to `pointer` is unsynchroinzed (or unordered).
That means thread 2 may dereference `pointer` while it still has the value `nullptr`.
Also, since `pointer` is a non-atomic type (i.e. a regular pointer), it may not be accessed this way between threads.
Technically you have a data race, and that leads to undefined behavior.

A solution is to strengthen memory ordering a bit. I think using acquire/release ordering on `atomic` should be sufficient:

```
auto&& atomic = std::atomic<int>{0};
std::atomic<int>* pointer = nullptr;

// thread 1
auto&& value = std::atomic<int>{1};
pointer = &value;
atomic.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
while (atomic.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != 2) {}
cout << value.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) << endl;

// thread 2
while (atomic.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != 1) {}
cout << pointer->load(std::memory_order_relaxed); << endl;
pointer->fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
atomic.store(2, std::memory_order_release) {}
```

With this ordering in place, the outcome is guaranteed to print

```
1
2
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but relaxed operations don't prevent synchronization, they simply don't impose any synchronization requirement.