# How does C++20's memory model differ from that of C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++20

C++11 introduces a new memory model that lets the abstract machine "running" C++11 code have a notion about multiple threads. It also introduces a set of memory orders by which memory load/store operations abide.

The wikipedia page of C++20 says that it has

> a revised memory model.

The reference it gives says that the memory model of C++11 has a number of flaws, which C++20 will revise.

Could someone please give some examples about the problems that come with C++11's memory model, and how that in C++20 would fix it?

Related question:
[Introduction to C++11's memory model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319146/c11-introduced-a-standardized-memory-model-what-does-it-mean-and-how-is-it-g)

Comment: I am so out of touch with C++ that I can't make a meaningful answer, but if you follow the entry on wikipedia it leads to [P0668R4: Revising the C++ memory model](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0668r4.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @PeterM suggests, its' a (subjectively) minor change due to issues discovered ex-post-facto with the formalization of the C++11 memory model.

The old model was defined so that different regimes of memory access could be implemented on common architectures  using more or less-costly sets of hardware instructions. Specifically, `memory_order_acquire` and `memory_order_release` were supposed to be implementable on ARM and Power CPU architectures using some kind of lightweight fence instructions. Unfortunately, it turns out that they can't (!); and this is also true for NVIDIA GPUs, although those weren't really targeted a decade back.

With this being the case, there were two options:

1. Implement to fit the standard - possible, but then performance would be pretty bad and that wasn't the idea.
2. Fix the standard to better accommodate these architectures (while not messing up the model completely)

Option 2 was apparently chosen.

For more details, read:

- Lahav, Vafeiadis, Kang, Hur, Dreyer, [Repairing Sequential Consistency in C/C++11](http://plv.mpi-sws.org/scfix/paper.pdf).
- Hans Boehm's C++-standard-committee paper [P0668R5: Revising the C++ memory model](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0668r5.html).

Comment: I [asked a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70554277/2752075) about what exactly was changed.