# What is the significance of 'strongly happens before' compared to '(simply) happens before'?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, language-lawyer, c++20

The standard defines several 'happens before' relations that extend the good old 'sequenced before' over multiple threads:

> #### [`[intro.races]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races)
>
> 11 An evaluation A **simply happens before** an evaluation B if either
>
> (11.1) — A is sequenced before B, or
> (11.2) — A synchronizes with B, or
> (11.3) — A simply happens before X and X simply happens before B.
>
> [Note 10: In the absence of consume operations, the happens before and simply happens before relations are identical. — end note]
>
> 12 An evaluation A **strongly happens before** an evaluation D if, either
>
> (12.1) — A is sequenced before D, or
> (12.2) — A synchronizes with D, and both A and D are sequentially consistent atomic operations
> ([atomics.order]), or
> (12.3) — there are evaluations B and C such that A is sequenced before B, B simply happens before C, and C is sequenced before D, or
> (12.4) — there is an evaluation B such that A strongly happens before B, and B strongly happens before D.
>
> [Note 11: Informally, if A strongly happens before B, then A appears to be evaluated before B in all contexts. Strongly happens before excludes consume operations. — end note]

<sup>(bold mine)</sup>

The difference between the two seems very subtle. 'Strongly happens before' is never true for matching pairs or release-acquire operations (unless both are seq-cst), but it **still respects release-acquire syncronization** in a way, since operations sequenced before a release 'strongly happen before' the operations sequenced after the matching acquire.

Why does this difference matter?

'Strongly happens before' was introduced in C++20, and pre-C++20, 'simply happens before' used to be called 'strongly happens before'. Why was it introduced?

[`[atomics.order]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#4) says that the total order of all seq-cst operations is consistent with 'strongly happens before'.

Does it mean that it's not consistent with 'simply happens before'? If so, why not?

---

I'm ignoring the plain 'happens before', because it differs from 'simply happens before' only in its handling of `memory_order_consume`, the use of which is [temporarily discouraged](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#note-1), since apparently most (all?) major compilers treat it as `memory_order_acquire`.

I've already seen [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58986135/2752075), but it doesn't explain why 'strongly happens before' exists, and doesn't fully address what it means (it just states that it doesn't respect release-acquire syncronization, which isn't completely the case).

---

Found [the proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0668r5.html) that introduced 'simply happens before'.

I don't fully understand it, but it explains following:

- 'Strongly happens before' is a weakened version of 'simply happens before'.
- The difference is only observable when seq-cst is mixed with aqc-rel on the same variable (I think, it means when an acquire load reads a value from a seq-cst store, or when an seq-cst load reads a value from a release store). But the exact effects of mixing the two are still unclear to me.

Comment: I don't really understand this argument in the proposal: `b = fetch_add(y)sc //1, which must be before y =sc 3`. There could be another store that overwrites its result.

Comment: @TSK It's assumed that there are no threads other than those 3, and they don't do anything more than what's specified in the example.

Comment: I mean exactly the other store `y =rel 1`

Comment: @TSK So you're imagining a case where `y=3` goes first, then `y=1`, then `y++`? But the second thread reads `y` again right after `y++`, and expects to see `3`, hence `y=3` must be after `y++`. (And remember that each invididual variable has a consistent modification order across all threads.)

Comment: If you reorder the two operations in the second thread, you can do the load before the fetch-add. The cpp reference page says "in many cases, memory_order_seq_cst atomic operations are reorderable with respect to other atomic operations performed by the same thread". On the other hand, it says seq_cst loads perform acquire operation so the reordering is probihited. This seems contradicting

Comment: @TSK The modification order of an individual variable is consistent with sequenced-before in each individual thread. Cppreference likely means that operations on *different* variables can be reordered relative to one another. I recommend checking out my interpretation of memory orders here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70585811/2752075

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's my current understanding, which could be incomplete or incorrect. A verification would be appreciated.

---

C++20 renamed `strongly happens before` to `simply happens before`, and introduced a new, more relaxed definition for `strongly happens before`, which imposes less ordering.

`Simply happens before` is used to reason about the presence of data races in your code. (Actually that would be the plain 'happens before', but the two are equivalent in absence of consume operations, the use of which is discouraged by the standard, since most (all?) major compilers treat them as acquires.)

The weaker `strongly happens before` is used to reason about the global order of seq-cst operations.

---

This change was introduced in proposal [P0668R5: Revising the C++ memory model](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0668r5.html), which is based on the paper [Repairing Sequential Consistency in C/C++11](http://plv.mpi-sws.org/scfix/paper.pdf) by Lahav et al (which I didn't fully read).

The proposal explains why the change was made. Long story short, the way most compilers implement atomics on Power and ARM architectures turned out to be non-conformant in rare edge cases, and fixing the compilers had a performance cost, so they fixed the standard instead.

The **change only affects you if you mix seq-cst operations with acquire-release operations on the same atomic variable** (i.e. if an acquire operation reads a value from a seq-cst store, or a seq-cst operation reads a value from a release store).

If you don't mix operations in this manner, then you're not affected (i.e. can treat `simply happens before` and `strongly happens before` as equivalent).

The gist of the change is that **the synchronization between a seq-cst operation and the corresponding acquire/release operation no longer affects the position of this specific seq-cst operation in the global seq-cst order**, but the synchronization itself is still there.

This makes the seq-cst order for the affected seq-cst operations moot, see below.

---

The proposal presents following example, and I'll try to explain my understanding of it:

```
atomic_int x = 0, y = 0;
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
// Thread 1
x.store(1, seq_cst);
y.store(1, release);
// Thread 2
b = y.fetch_add(1, seq_cst); // b = 1 (the value of y before increment)
c = y.load(relaxed); // c = 3
// Thread 3
y.store(3, seq_cst);
a = x.load(seq_cst); // a = 0
```

The comments indicate one of the ways that this code can execute, which the standard used to forbid (before this change), but which actually can happen on the affected architectures.

The execution proceeds as follows:

```
    Sequenced-before (and strongly-happens-before) in each individual thread       | Variable modification orders                   | Global seq_cst order
    T1                            T2                      T3                         X                       Y                        
                                                                                 .-- .load(seq_cst) == 0                              (3)
.-> x.store(1, seq_cst)                                                          |   .store(1, seq_cst)                               (4)
|   y.store(1, release) -.                                                       |                           .store(1, release)
|                        '-sync-> y.fetch_add(1, seq_cst)                        |                           .fetch_add(1, seq_cst)   (1)
|                                                         y.store(3, seq_cst)    |                           .store(3, seq_cst)       (2)
|                                 y.load(relaxed)         x.load(seq_cst) == 0 --'                           .load(relaxed)
|                                                            |
|                                                           coherence-
|                                                           ordered
|                                                           before
|                                                            |
'------------------------------------------------------------'
```

Here time flows downwards.

But, as usual, there's no single timeline. Rather, there are several, some of which coincide in some aspects. Each column represents a separate timeline (ordering).

T1,T2,T3 represent the sequenced-before relation (internal to each thread), which implies strongly-happens-before too.

X,Y are the modification orders of the respective variables. (I've included reads, even though they're don't technically Each thread must be consistent with each variable, but threads don't have to be consistent with one another. Each variable's modification order must be consistent with the global seq-cst order (only counting seq-cst operations on those variables).

On the first glance, `x.load(seq_cst) == 0` is in a weird place in the modification order of X (hence the connecting line leading to it) but this is completely legal (doesn't contradict the previous paragraph), regardless of the C++20 changes.

The "sync" arrow represents the synchronizes-with relation. The seq-cst order would normally agree with it, but since this synchronization is between a seq-cst and a non-seq-cst operation, it doesn't happen. In the "seq-cst" column, you can see a discontinuity at this point.

There's also a ["coherence-ordered before"](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#3) arrow, which is a new relation introduced in this proposal, which is only used to define the global seq-cst order, and apparently imposes no synchronization (unlike release-acquire operations). (In this case this relation coincides with common sense: if a load doesn't see the value written by the store, then the load goes before the store.)

Comment: What prohibits (2 3 4 1) SC order here? I don't see any SC ordering between (2) and (1)... If it's (1 2 3 4), how is it determined that (2) follows (1)?

Comment: @deshalder IIRC (1 2 3 4) is not *forced*. It's just that it's *possible*.

Comment: Also, what is the modification order of `y` here? Is it (2), `y.store(1, release)`, (1)?.. I'm totally not sure... If it is, (2) could be coherence-ordered before (1)... and precede it in SC order then...

Comment: @ledonter Sorry, I'm late. I believe it has to be `y.store(1, release)`, (1), `y.load(relaxed)`, (2) to be consistent with each thread. I updated the answer, should be more clear now.

Comment: Well I guess the `y.load` would the last one, at least it's the last one in your updated answer (and it seems to make sense); also, AFAIU, loads do not participate in modification order; if anything, after reading this question I asked another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72370293/how-is-modification-order-of-a-variable-defined-in-c, I think it clarifies things a bit and is generally consistent with your response