# How to keep GCC from reordering writes to special memory regions?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, g++

Suppose I have code such as

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>

namespace
{
struct Thing {
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t c;
    uint8_t d;
};

auto& magicRegister = *reinterpret_cast<volatile uint8_t*>(0x1234);
auto magicMemory = reinterpret_cast<Thing*>(0x2000);  // 0x2000 - 0x20ff
}

int main()
{
    magicMemory[0] = { .a = 1, .b = 2, .c = 3, .d = 4 };
    magicRegister = 0xff;   // Transfer

    magicMemory[0].d = 5;
    magicRegister = 0xff;   // Transfer
}
```

in which writing `0xff` to the byte located in address `0x1234` makes the system copy 256 bytes from the region starting at `0x2000` to an inaccessible memory. The contents of the memory region only matter when the transfer takes place.

How can I **guarantee** that GCC's optimization won't mess up the order of operations?

---

I see a few options.

1. Make `magicMemory` volatile: I dislike this, because the contents of the memory region don't matter until the transfer is initiated.
2. Add `asm("" ::: "memory");` before each transfer: simple and effective, but may prevent some unrelated code from being properly optimized.

```cpp
int main()
{
    magicMemory[0] = { .a = 1, .b = 2, .c = 3, .d = 4 };
    asm("" ::: "memory");
    magicRegister = 0xff;   // Transfer

    magicMemory[0].d = 5;
    asm("" ::: "memory");
    magicRegister = 0xff;   // Transfer
}
```

3. Same as #2, but add

```
asm(""
    :
    : "m"(*reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(0x2000)),
      "m"(*reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(0x2001)),
      "m"(*reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(0x2002)),
      // ...
      "m"(*reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(0x20fd)),
      "m"(*reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(0x20fe)),
      "m"(*reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(0x20ff)));
```

instead: stupid, but technically should work. Sadly, it crashes the GCC port I'm using.

---

EDIT: What if I also had this:

```cpp
uint8_t unrelatedVariable;

int main()
{
    unrelatedVariable = 5;   // This is redundant and should be optimized away

    // same as before

    unrelatedVariable = 6;
}
```

It is possible to fix the ordering of accesses to `magicRegister` and `magicMemory` while not affecting `unrelatedVariable`?

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this is to use **memory barrier** or *atomics* to ensure the consistency of writes. Indeed, not only GCC can reorder writes, but most modern **processors can also reorder memory instructions** (although many of them do not reorder multiple writes).

[Memory barriers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence)  establishes memory *synchronization ordering of non-atomic* and relaxed atomic accesses, as instructed by order, *without an associated atomic operation*. Here is how to use them in your case:

```cpp
int main()
{
    magicMemory[0] = { .a = 1, .b = 2, .c = 3, .d = 4 };

    // No reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered after this
    // Also prevents all preceding writes from moving past all subsequent stores.
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);

    // Here we are sure that magicMemory has been written
    magicRegister = 0xff;   // Transfer

    // This barrier is needed not to update magicMemory before the tranfer
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);

    magicMemory[0].d = 5;

    // Same as before
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);

    magicRegister = 0xff;   // Transfer
}
```

Note that if you need to also read data between the writes, then it is probably wise to use the `std::memory_order_acq_rel` ordering for the memory barriers.

You can find information about memory ordering [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order).

C++ atomics can help you if you need to write the `Thing` structure in one shot and to control the consistency of the write before the transfer. However, [unless you use C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref), you cannot make atomic operation on any memory area (atomic reference).

Finally, yes, `volatile` does not really match with your expectations (the compiler cannot reorder volatile writes, but the processor still can, like some PowerPC processors). Here is what the standard says about it:

> Within a thread of execution, accesses (reads and writes) through volatile glvalues cannot be reordered past observable side-effects (including other volatile accesses) that are sequenced-before or sequenced-after within the same thread, but this order is not guaranteed to be observed by another thread, since volatile access does not establish inter-thread synchronization.
> In addition, **volatile accesses are not atomic** (concurrent read and write is a data race) **and do not order memory** (non-volatile memory accesses may be freely reordered around the volatile access).

You can also find additional information about the interaction between volatile accesses, memory fences and CPU writes reordering in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307071) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65295907).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I understand, that will also affect unrelated memory accesses, right? Is it possible for it to only affect `magicRegister` and `magicMemory`? See the example I added to my question.

Comment: Yes, that will also affect unrelated memory accesses. Concerning the local effect: AFAIK, not for the writes in this cases (for reads, you can play with atomic references and the `std::memory_order_consume` despite it is discouraged). Actually, `unrelatedVariable` and `magicMemory` should be optimized differently in your case since `magicRegister` and `magicMemory` are implicitly linked due to their special location in memory, but the compiler is not aware of that. I doubt there is a generic way (ie. hardware independent) to make the compiler know this (even specifically GCC).