# Is atomic variable in C++ implemented using volatile and CAS?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, atomic, volatile

`AtomicInteger` in Java is implemented using volatile and CAS mechanism. [source code](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java#L54)

But, how C++11 implement atomic?

Comment: The implementation of atomic types in Java is not written in Java - it is based on what happens in the JVM (which interprets the bytecode, and takes action on the host system).    Similarly, in C++, the implementation of atomic types depends on the implementation (i.e. the specifics of how the compiler and standard library do things for the target machine).

Answer (score 3):

`std::atomic` is part of the C++ language; on ISAs that support atomic instructions it directly translates to those instructions. On x86 for example there's the `LOCK` prefix that can be used with loads and stores, as well as the `LOCK CMPXCHG` (the "CAS" instruction).

In addition to CPU instructions, `std::atomic` affects the memory order semantics of the program. For more details refer to [C++ atomics and memory ordering](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/12/01/c-atomics-and-memory-ordering/) and the [C++ memory model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319146/c11-introduced-a-standardized-memory-model-what-does-it-mean-and-how-is-it-g).

On an ISA lacking atomic instructions the compiler is allowed to implement it using helper routines/locks, in which case [`is_lock_free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free) could return `false` (this is unlikely to happen for primitive types as all SMP systems support atomic operations natively).

Answer (score 1):

if it's possible `std::atomic` will use a native assembly level instruction that will atomically assign a value. if it's not possible (whether it's because you're using a non-native datatype or because the cpu doesn't support such an instruction) it will default to using an `std::lock` to ensure the access to it is safe (so not actually atomic at that point)

Answer (score 1):

`volatile` in C++ means not the same as in Java, in C++ it does not imply memory ordering.

Atomics are implemented using compiler extensions (intrinsics/builtin functions).

Answer (score 0):

I've found something inside the [atomic header source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/atomic) which redirects to [this page](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html). Then you'll see the index with [Implementation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html#Implementation) and, under that and many other  things, there is [Integers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html#ImplIntegers).